# Azure web role with cdn

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

I have a web role with 2 web application on it.( one is web application the other is wcf application).
The static content in the web application is from azure cdn. I put my static content under cdn directory and on the html i refer to the cdn endpoint.
my problem is
that sometime see that the entire static content not getting from the cdn.and the entire web page is without css/images/javascript files and after 5-10 minutes everything up again.

Has anyone see this kind of behavior? - i always check the status in Microsoft web site and every time i see that the cdn is working properly.

How does the cdn react with 2 web role on the same instance. maybe that's what causing the problem that it switch back and forth?

thanks allot

Comment: Can u run fiddler to get more info about the problem and provide info here?

Comment: hmm. that's a good idea. i'll try it. The problem is that its unpredictable phenomenon and i never know when it happen.

Comment: Hi. unfortunately i couldn't see this behavior anymore. but a similiar issue happen to me on cdn from blob storage. i ask for a file and i get 504 in the http response.

Answer (score 1):

If your static content is not changing frequently, I would suggest you to setup higher Cache limit may be for an year and this will help you to load content faster. The link below explain more on how to do it:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2011/03/18/best-practices-for-the-windows-azure-content-delivery-network.aspx

**[More info]**

IF you have random issues with your Windows Azure CDN cache, it is suggested to contact Windows Azure Support Team and discuss this problem. They will dig deeper to look for the root cause. The above info is very less to determine the actual root cause.

Comment: I already set my cache expire to one year. once the client gets the data. the css and js i always change their file name when i change them. but my problem always occur on images so thats not the issue